# Sequelize create belongTo instance with reference

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize for my new NodeJs project

I defined two models: BusinessUnit and Store with this association: `Store.belongsTo(BusinessUnit);`

```
  module.test_data_insertion = function() {
    models.BusinessUnit.findOne({
      where: {
        BUID: "001"
      }
    }).then(element => {
      fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function(file) {
        var contents = fs.readFileSync(dir + file);
        var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
        models.Store.create({
          StoreId: jsonContent.StoreId,
          StoreName: jsonContent.StoreName,
          businessUnitId: element.id
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

I don't find to right way to reference the element in my Store, I would like something like this where I don't have to reference an id field directly

```
module.test_data_insertion = function() {
    models.BusinessUnit.findOne({
      where: {
        BUID: "001"
      }
    }).then(element => {
      fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function(file) {
        var contents = fs.readFileSync(dir + file);
        var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
        models.Store.create({
          StoreId: jsonContent.StoreId,
          StoreName: jsonContent.StoreName,
          businessUnit: element
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

It should be simple but I don't see it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your association are setup correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
module.test_data_insertion = function() {
models.BusinessUnit.findOne({
  where: {
    BUID: "001"
  }
}).then(element => {
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function(file) {
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(dir + file);
    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
    element.setStore({
      StoreId: jsonContent.StoreId,
      StoreName: jsonContent.StoreName,

    });
  });
});
};
```

please read [belongsTo](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to.js~BelongsTo.html) from doc which enables a `set` method,

However please note if this is a one to many relationship(one business unit with many stores) you may need to switch to `belongsToMany` it has `add` method. because setStore would override previous set.

Also, i'm not sure if any of those method would work inside `.forEach` correctly since they are promise, you may need to switch to a traditional `for loop`.

Comment: It was almost right, it's the contrary. `models.Store.create({
          StoreId: jsonContent.StoreId,
          StoreName: jsonContent.StoreName
        }).then(store => {
          store.setBusinessUnit(element);
        });`